# The Method add(String) is undefined for type player

Tags: java

I think i have something mixed up here.   on the players.add(name)
my instructions were.. 
"

Add a new method called addPlayer.   It should take a String for the player name as an 
    argument.  Use the String to create a new Player and add it to the list of players."

```
package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame;
import edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PhraseGameController { 

    private Phrase currentPhrase; 
    private ArrayList<Character> guessed; 
    private ArrayList<Player> players;  //2


    PhraseGameController Player = new PhraseGameController();   //3


    public void addPlayer(String name) {
        Player players= new Player(name);
        players.add(name);                    //// <<< Error Is Here

    }

    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }                                //4







    public boolean doPlayerGuess(Character play) {

        Character guess = Character.toUpperCase(play);
        if(guessed.contains(play)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("the letter was already guessed");
    } else if (!String.valueOf(play).matches("[A-Z]")) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("the guess should be a letter from A­Z");
    }

    guessed.add(guess); 
    return currentPhrase.guessLetter(guess);

    }







    public PhraseGameController(){
    currentPhrase = new Phrase("This is only a test");
    guessed = new ArrayList<Character>();       
    }



     public Phrase getCurrentPhrase() {  
        return currentPhrase;
    }
    public void setCurrentPhrase(Phrase currentPhrase) {
        this.currentPhrase = currentPhrase;
    }

    public void setGuessedLetters(ArrayList<Character> guessed) {
        this.guessed = guessed;
    }
    public ArrayList<Character> getGuessedLetters() { 
        return guessed;
    }
}
```

> ```
> and my player class..
> ```

```
    package edu.htc.java1.phrasegame.model;

public class Player {

public int currentScore;
public int highScore;
public String name;


public String getPlayerName() {
    return "Me";
}
public Player(String getName) {
    getName = "Me";
}
public int modifyScore(int points) {
    currentScore = points + currentScore;
    return currentScore;
}

 public void finalizeScore() {
     if ( currentScore >= highScore){
         highScore = currentScore;
     }  
         currentScore = 0;

 }



// Getters and setters
public int getCurrentScore() {
    return currentScore;
}
public int getHighScore() {
    return highScore;
}


}
```

Comment: Should you be adding `name` or `player`? `Use the String to create a new Player and add it to the list of players.`

Comment: Am i not doing that? Name of the player? Or am I thinking too much? name.add();

Comment: Let me rephrase: What do you add to a list of players, a name or a player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `Player` object instead of `String` name like:

```
public void addPlayer(String name) {
    Player player = new Player(name);
    players.add(player); // add the player object not name
}
```

Comment: Better rename the local variable too.

Comment: @user3381466 get used to it. That's what programming is all about :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
public void addPlayer(String name) {
    players.add(new Player(name)); // add the player object not name
}
```

Comment: Code-only questions do not help the OP understand. Please provide some explanation along with the code.